# Angular tab list array keep sorting correct

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create something similar to the tags function on StackOverflow.
Here's a Stackblitz of how far I got:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dhsql

No search bar, instead the user names must be clicked.
How can I keep my array `selected` with the correct names and remove the relevant object from the array after clicking `remove`?

Is there any trick to do so? I had a look at `array.prototype.splice()` but I had the issue that every entry after the one deleted moved to index-1 which had the effect that `array` wasn't sorted correctly anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an element from array using [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Remove_1_element_from_index_3), you need to use this syntax - `array.splice(index,1)`. To get the index, you can use the `*ngFor` with index variable and pass it to `removeUser()` function as shown below.

In your template -

```
<div *ngFor="let user of selected; let i = index" class="inline-block cursor-default font-medium mr-2 mt-2 rounded-full py-1 px-3 text-sm align-middle bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-200 text-blue-500">
{{ user.name }}
<span (click)="removeUser(i)" class="text-gray-500 cursor-pointer">remove</span>
</div>
```

In your component ts file -

```
removeUser(index) {
  this.selected.splice(index,1);
}
```

Checkout the working code here - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbu2zt)

In this case the array is still sorted in the order in which the tags are added/clicked. Assuming this is what you want.

This is also efficient because you do not have to loop through the `this.selected` array in-order to find the object that has to be removed.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I am most fond of.
I totally missed using the index in the `*ngFor` directive.

Answer (score 1):

If many tags are not expected, you can try to use filter:

```
removeUser(user) {
    this.selected = this.selected.filter(selectedUser => selectedUser.name !== user.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete object by filtering the array

```
this.selected = this.selected.filter(ele => ele != user);
```